# Using AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal with a certificate throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, x509certificate2

I created a console application using .NET framework 4.7.2 to connect to the Azure Resource Manager API using these nuget packages:

- Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent: v1.18.0 | [download link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/)
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent: v1.18.0 | [download link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/)

This is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace AzResourceManager
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "********-****-****-****-************";
            var subscriptionId = "********-****-****-****-************";
            var tenantId = "********-****-****-****-************"; 
            var cert = GetCertificate("********************************");

            var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, cert, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            foreach (var rGroup in azure.ResourceGroups.List())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rGroup.Name);
            }
        }

        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbPrint)
        {
            var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            try
            {
                var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
                if (certCollection.Count <= 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to load certificate from store");
                return certCollection[0];
            }
            finally
            {
                certStore.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the execution reaches this line

```
foreach (var rGroup in azure.ResourceGroups.List())
```

the application throws a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I installed the certificate in the application registered in the Azure Active Directory and in my laptop. I tried updating some packages but the result is the same. The only package I cannot update to its latest version is `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` (latest version: v4.4.1), I only can update it to version v3.19.8

This is the stack trace for that exception:

```
at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.ClientAssertionCertificate.Sign(String message)\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.JsonWebToken.Sign(IClientAssertionCertificate credential) in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\ClientCreds\\JsonWebToken.cs:line 100\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientKey.AddToParameters(IDictionary`2 parameters) in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\ClientCreds\\ClientKey.cs:line 127\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__64.MoveNext() in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\Flows\\AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs:line 0\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext() in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\Flows\\AcquireTokenHandlerBase.cs:line 198\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenForClientCommonAsync>d__49.MoveNext() in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\AuthenticationContext.cs:line 541\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__27.MoveNext() in c:\\workspace\\azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet-v3-master-VS2017\\src\\ADAL.PCL\\AuthenticationContext.cs:line 239\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.CertificateAuthenticationProvider.<AuthenticateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.ApplicationTokenProvider.<LoginSilentAsync>d__33.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication.ApplicationTokenProvider.<LoginSilentAsync>d__24.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n  

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication.AzureCredentials.<ProcessHttpRequestAsync>d__24.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperations.<ListWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n 

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsOperationsExtensions.<ListAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core.Extensions.Synchronize[TResult](Func`1 function)\r\n   
at Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.ResourceGroupsImpl.List()\r\n   
at AzResourceManager.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\\Demos\\ARM\\AzResourceManager\\AzResourceManager\\Program.cs:line 27
```

If I use a `secret` instead of the certificate the code works correctly.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Authentication;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace AzResourceManager
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientId = "********-****-****-****-************";
            var secret = "********-****-****-****-************";
            var subscriptionId = "********-****-****-****-************";
            var tenantId = "********-****-****-****-************"; 

            var creds = new AzureCredentialsFactory().FromServicePrincipal(clientId, secret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);            
            var azure = Azure.Authenticate(creds).WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

            foreach (var rGroup in azure.ResourceGroups.List())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(rGroup.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

these are the packages installed: (packages.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.BatchAI.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerRegistry.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerService.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventHub.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Locks.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Msi.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent" version="1.18.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="3.14.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.17" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.18" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.4" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Is it possible that your tenant is missing access to some subscriptions? You can check the list with get-azurermcontext -ListAvailable

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to get the results using the [Resource Groups List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/list).  I have tried myself and I am not getting any error while using your code and it worked fine for me.  Please make sure that your registered application service principal has been provided at least Reader access to your subscription.  Please follow the document [Manage access using RBAC and the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) for assigning roles to Azure resources.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same frustrating System.NullReferenceException when trying to use the exported certificare with **.CER** extension,
but when exporting the certificate in **.PFX** format with password: the overloaded FromServicePrincipal function succeeds

```
var credentials = SdkContext
        .AzureCredentialsFactory
        .FromServicePrincipal(
             "********-****-****-****-************", // clientId
              @"c:\cert.pfx", // certificate file path
             "123456", // certificate password
             "********-****-****-****-************", //tenantId
             AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
```